# WebGL Won't Render

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've basically given up on figuring out what is wrong with this code. It just won't render. It's supposed to load an .obj file with a custom .png texture wrapped around it. You should then be able to rotate around the image by dragging the mouse. I have no idea what this could be. Is the object just not appearing in the camera field of view? All help greatly appreciated! P.S. The .js files do load properly. I've tested this build on a simpler iteration and I haven't had to add any new functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

    <script>

    var container;

    var camera, scene, renderer;

    var group, text, plane;

    var targetRotationX = 0;
    var targetRotationOnMouseDownX = 0;

    var targetRotationY = 0;
    var targetRotationOnMouseDownY = 0;

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

    var mouseY = 0;
    var mouseYOnMouseDown = 0;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    var finalRotationY


    init();
    animate();


    function init() {

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

            // scene

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 100;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // lights

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( light );

            group = new THREE.Object3D();

            // texture

            var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                console.log( item, loaded, total );

            };

            var texture = new THREE.Texture();

            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };

            var onError = function ( xhr ) {
            };


            var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'textures/3poster.png', function ( image ) {

                texture.image = image;
                texture.needsUpdate = true;

            } );

            // model

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'obj/tshirt.obj', function ( object ) {

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                        child.material.map = texture;

                    }

                } );

                scene.add( object );

            }, onProgress, onError );

            // renderer

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );


            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function modelLoadedCallback(object) {

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( object, material );
            group.add(mesh);
            scene.add( group );

        }


        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;

            mouseYOnMouseDown = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
            targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

            targetRotationY = targetRotationOnMouseDownY + (mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
            targetRotationX = targetRotationOnMouseDownX + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.02;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

            document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;

                mouseYOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationX = targetRotationOnMouseDownX + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;

                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationY = targetRotationOnMouseDownY + (mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown) * 0.05;

            }

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

         group.rotation.y += ( targetRotationX - group.rotation.y ) * 0.1;

         finalRotationY = (targetRotationY - group.rotation.x); 

         if (group.rotation.x  <= 1 && group.rotation.x >= -1 ) {

            group.rotation.x += finalRotationY * 0.1;
        }
        if (group.rotation.x  > 1 ) {

            group.rotation.x = 1
        }

        if (group.rotation.x  < -1 ) {

            group.rotation.x = -1
        }

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does the model appear if you remove the `object.traverse()` logic from your code?

Comment: No, unfortunately nothing changes. I think it may have something to do with the grouping logic. I may not need it.

Comment: can you put somewhere the .obj file?

Comment: The issue can't be the .obj file. I ran a less complicated version of the viewer with the model and it worked. It's something to do with the code above just not rendered it correctly.

Comment: I can copy/paste the code locally to see what the problem is but i need the obj file.

Comment: Oh okay. I put it on Dropbox. Thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/s/el9jy7zr9tycg2k/tshirt.obj?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you dont have an element named `container` at this line in your code

```
container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
```

comment it out (since you already have a valid variable called `container`) and you will see your model.

Comment: Awesome. It works! Thank you. Would you by any chance know why it's not rotating? Haha.

Comment: you never call `modelLoadedCallback()` so the object never makes it into the `group`